# Remove dot prefix "./" from std::filesystem::path

Tags: c++

Is there a simple way to strip away the starting `./` of a path. For example: I have a path `./x/y` and i want to convert it to `x/y` (without the first dot and slash). Is there a standard way of doing it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace filesystem = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    auto path = filesystem::path{"./x/y"};
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
    std::cout << ???? << std::endl; // How do I do this?
}
```

Comment: Does [`relative_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/relative_path) give you what you want?

Comment: @NathanOliver I have been looking at it but cannot get it to work. Do you happend to have a working example lying around, or a hint of how to do it? https://godbolt.org/z/e5eGcsoar

Comment: @NathanOliver Found it: https://godbolt.org/z/rcE4drE4q

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the problem could be solved with `std::filesystem::relative()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace filesystem = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    auto path = filesystem::path{"./x"};
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
    std::cout << filesystem::relative(path, "./") << std::endl; // 
}
```

Produces

```
"./x"
"x"
```